# How to call same api with different params on click of button in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, api

I have made 3 different custom buttons:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={selectClosed}>
    <Text>Closed</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={selectPending}>
    <Text>Pending</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={selectComplete}>
    <Text>Complete</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and their onPress functions:

```
const selectClosed = () => {
    getShiftDetails.bind(null, 'closed');
};
const selectPending = () => {
    getShiftDetails.bind(null, 'pending');
};
const selectComplete = () => {
    getShiftDetails.bind(null, 'complete');
};
```

Below is how I am making my api call:

```
const getShiftDetails = useCallback(
    (
        page = 1,
        limit = 20,
        mode: 'pending' | 'complete' | 'closed' = 'complete',
    ) => {
            const payload = {
                page,
                limit,
                status: [mode],
            };
            ApiFunctions.post(apiUrl + '/shift', payload)
                .then(
                    // other stuff
                )
                .catch((err: any) => {
                    // other stuff
                });
    },
    [user],
);
```

By default my api call is being done with `mode` as `complete`. Now if I click on `pending` button then another api call should be made with `mode` as `pending`. But this is not happening. I am not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: `getShiftDetails` expects **three** arguments, with `mode` being the _third_. When you bind it, I believe the argument you're giving is what's provided as the *first* argument into the bound function. But in this case, the first parameter is `page`. Try moving the `mode` parameter to be first (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#partially_applied_functions)

Comment: You're also using `.bind` wrong. Should be like `const selectClosed = getShiftDetails.bind(null, 1, 20, 'closed');` instead. See [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using customHooks. (When options are changed, call is made again.)

```js
const useFetch = (url, options) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(async() => {
    const res = await fetch(url, options);
    const json = await res.json();

    setResponse(json);
  }, [options]);

  return response;
};
```

use hooks:

```js
const payload = {
  page = 1,
  limit = 20,
  status: 'pending',
};

const { response } = useFetch("url", payload)
```